Custom Link not clickable on android (react-native)
I have created custom links for my react native app in this format exampleApp://feed/:feed-id, they work fine on ios but when I share them on android they don't appear clickable on messages or whatsapp or anywhere else. What can I do so they appear as links and become clickable.
I cannot host the urls on web so can't use universal links.

Please provide more details: Is the problem with the links not becoming clickable in the chat apps, or is your app not opening relevant links at all? If it's the former this question is off-topic for StackOverflow, if it's the latter then please edit that detail into your question.
